# How to perform a groupBy in Laravel 5.8?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-query-builder

I have a table with 41 rows

[image]

I did

```
public function types()
{
    return DB::table('graphs')->groupBy('title')->get();
}
```

I kept getting

[image]

Can someone please help ?

I expected to get these 3

```
['MBN_PRIVATE','MBN_GUEST','SPWIFI'];
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In MySql strict mode, you can't return non aggregated fields in a `group by` query.
If you need only the title's values add a select or a pluck method

```
public function types()
{
    return DB::table('graphs')->groupBy('title')->pluck('title')->toArray();
}
```

Comment: @kyo it's better to use the pluck method, i've edited my answer

Comment: You tend to see this most often when it did work as you wrote it, but then newer MySQL installs, default to the more strict form, and break this query.

Answer (score 1):

Try orderBy() instead of groupBy().

```
public function types()
{
    return DB::table('graphs')->orderBy('title')->get();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answering , but it is not working. it showed all.